# $[S]$ means linear span of S. Then $[S] = [[S]]$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> **My definition of span**:
>
> Suppose a vector space $(V,+,\cdot)$, and
>
> $$S = \{u_1,\cdots,u_n\}$$
>
> (and $S$ is a subset of $V$, not a subspace)
>
> $$[S]=:\bigcap_{W\subset V, W\supseteq S} W$$
>
> In other words, $[S]$ is, by definition, the intersection of all $W$,
>   such that $W$ is a subspace of $V$ and $W$ contains $S$.

Well, then I need to prove that

$$[S] = [[S]]$$

My strategy:

$[[S]]$ means the intersection of all subspaces that contain $[S]$. If all the subspaces contains $[S]$, so does their intersection. Therefore, $[S]\subset[[S]]$

However, I'm having trouble proving the converse:

$$[[S]]\subset[S]$$

Any hints?

Comment: "Vectors that are linear combinations of linear combinations of vectors in $S$, are just linear combinations of vectors in $S$"

Comment: @AndreaMori yes, but I can't use this definition, I must use the intersection one

Comment: No, you must not! :) Or maybe, just prove preliminarly that that intersection is just the set of linear combinations of vectors in $S$

Comment: Do you know that $[S]$ is a subspace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $[S]$ is a subspace containing $[S]$.  Thus $[S]$ is included in the intersection which defines $[[S]]$.

Comment: Well, so: $[[S]]$ is the intersection of all subspaces that contain $[S]$. But $[S]$ is a subspace, therefore it is in all the subspaces that contains $[S]$. So if every subspace contains $[S]$, then $[S]$ is in the intersection. The intersection is by definition $[[S]]$. But maybe $[S]$ is inside $[[S]]$, not exactly equal to it. Could you help me?

Comment: [S] is among the sets you are intersecting, and every other set includes [S] as a subset. So the intersection is [S] itself.

Comment: By the way to prove that [S] is a subspace, use @AndreaMori suggestion on the comments.

Comment: @rewritten I think the easiest way to prove that $[S]$ is a subspace is to notice that if $X$ and $Y$ are subspaces, so must their intersection (since, if two sets are closed under some operation, so is their intersection) - it's more direct from definition.

Comment: @Meelo: Except that you need this for intersections of arbitrary collections of subpaces, not just $2$ at a time. The proof is just the same for the general intersection case.

Answer (score 0):

Apply your  own definition on $[S]$ ,

see that  $[[S]] $ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $[S]$ and $[S]$ contains itself so $[[S]] \subseteq[S]$

Answer (score 0):

$\operatorname{sp} A$ is the smallest subspace containing $A$.

It follows from this that if $A \subset V$ and $V$ is a subspace, then $\operatorname{sp} A \subset V$.

Since we have $\operatorname{sp} S \subset \operatorname{sp} S$ and
$\operatorname{sp} S$ is a subspace, we have $\operatorname{sp} (\operatorname{sp} S) \subset \operatorname{sp} S$.

It is also clear that if $A \subset B$, then $\operatorname{sp} A \subset \operatorname{sp} B$, so
we have $\operatorname{sp} S \subset \operatorname{sp} (\operatorname{sp} S)$.