# Prove span(span(s)) = span(s)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be a subset of a vector space $V$ . Prove that $\text{Span}(\text{Span}(S)) = \text{Span}(S)$.

What I tried: I know that this proof revolves around the fact that a linear combination of elements = a linear combination of more fundamental elements.

Comment: $\mathrm{Span}(S)$ is a vector subspace. Now use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609596/prove-that-mathrmspans-s-for-a-subspace-s/1609608#1609608

Comment: Depends on your definition of Span. Whichever definition you use, you should prove that Span$(S)$ is the smallest vector space containing $S$. Then your result drops out.

Comment: Span(S) is the smallest subspace containing S. Span(Span(S)) ist the smallest subspace containing Span(S). As Span(S) ist already a subspace, Span(Span(S)) = Span(S)

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1050861

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $v\in $ Span(Span(S)), then $v$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of Span(S). Hence, $v = a_1w_1 +...+ a_nw_n$, where $w_i \in$ Span(S). Now, $w_i \in $ Span(S) $\implies$ $w_i = b_1z_1 +...+b_mz_m$ where $z_m$ is in $S$. Now, just replace each term in the first equation with its expansion and you have written $v$ as a linear combination of elements of $S$.

Comment: Love this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The span $\text{span}(T)$ of some subset $T$ of a vector space $V$ is the smallest subspace containing $T$.

Thus, for any subspace $U$ of $V$, we have $\text{span}(U) = U$. This holds in particular for $U=\text{span}(S)$, since the span of a set is always a subspace.

Comment: Probably OP is using the definition of span according to which it’s the set of all finite linear combinations of elements of the set in question. Then the fact that it’s the smallest vector space containing the set needs to be proved.

Comment: @Lubin if so, Kyle's answer is more appropriate, although maybe the result of the span being the smallest subspace containing the set is a known theorem at this point.

Comment: @HowDoIMath: Why not both? Both answers seem fine to me.

Comment: I would have done it the way you did it, with the proof included; but I gave the plus-mark to Kyle, because it was really more efficient than our ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$. By definition, $\text{Span}(S) = \left\{x \, | \, x = a_1 s_1 + \dots + a_n s_n, a_i \in F, s_i \in S \right\}$ and $\text{Span}(\text{Span}(S)) = \left\{x \, | x = a_1 s_1 + \dots + a_n s_n, a_i \in F, s_n \in \text{Span}(S) \right\}$. So to show equality, you can just show $\text{Span}(S) \subset \text{Span}(\text{Span}(S))$ and $\text{Span}(\text{Span}(S)) \subset \text{Span}(S)$.